# Why did the tugboat explode?

Tags: resident-evil, resident-evil-revelations

The heroes make their way to the bridge, only to find the controls smashed and the ship adrift. To make matters worse they then see their tugboat explode, and suddenly Jill is grabbed by a mysterious man.

**What caused the tugboat to explode?**

Answer (score 2):

The ship contains a laboratory where a Veltro operative is attempting to create a T-Abyss virus vector capable of infecting the world's oceans. Therefore, the  Federal Bioterrorism Commission (FBC) wants to find and destroy the laboratory. Ultimately what happens is that Jessica neutralizes the virus in the lab and then activates a self-destruct sequence on the ship to destroy the lab for good. The explosion is a depiction of the ship's self-destruct mechanism going off.

Comment: It's the tugboat explosion that I'm asking not the ship.

Comment: The self destruct mechanism also includes the tugboat? The ship starts moving and the tugboat cables break,why?this is the self destruction mecanism?